# Editing outdated source code in an answer

Tags: discussion, edits

I was trying to [suggest an edit to the source code in an obsolete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2141128). I linked to the author of the library explaining that it no longer exists, and I have tested it myself.

Is it not proper form to update out of date method calls? (It seemed like it got rejected without even reading the evidence.)

Comment: As one of the people who rejected the edit. I did not read the evidence. Nor do I think I should have because it was relevant to the code that you were editing which makes it more like a comment. Which is why it was rejected for being a comment to the post.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I do appreciate it. In the case that I was able to comment would it be worth noting to future people that the method is obsolete?

Comment: Yes I do believe that it would have been good to post it as a comment because someone is likely to find that question and try and implement it and encounter the same problems as you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never change code in answers; any change in code changes the meaning of a post. That answer applies to the specific question, for the version, for the time period.

Thus, if you really insist, you can comment on the post, and have the answerer change the answer. You can also post another answer (likely after asking the original answerer
 - but if you copy code, be sure to credit the OP and make it clear what you're doing/changing.

Comment: I see, I am unable to comment. So I guess in those cases I just ignore it and let the next person try to debug the code on their own... Or would it be better to add a new answer since I can't comment? I just hate to think of people running into the same issue I did tonight.

Comment: @MattCarrier I'm of the opinion that nobody should be copying code out of StackOverflow answers into their compiler; you need to understand the answer, and reproduce it in a way that works for you. Also, yes, adding an answer is a very acceptable solution; but make sure it's clear what you're doing

Comment: Fair enough. I do agree about straight copying code out. Not the best idea.